# Codeigniter Try Catch Transaction

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions

I have this transaction and try catch statement that checks the value of each `$_POST['count']` is not less than 0. *the rollback only happens when the if statement is false it doesn't include the past update which is incorrect

```
$this->db->trans_begin();
foreach($_POST['ID'] as $val => $r)
{

        //Gets Count            
        $this->db->select('count');
        $this->db->from('table1');
        $this->db->where('table_id', $r);
        $oc = $this->db->get()->row('count');
        $nc = (($oc) - $_POST['count'][$val]);

        //Gets Total
        $this->db->select('cost');
        $this->db->from('table1');
        $this->db->where('table_id', $r);
        $ot = $this->db->get()->row('cost');
        $total = ($ot + $total);
        try{
            if($nc > 0){
                //Updates Quantity  
                $process = array(
                    'current_count' => $nc,
                );

                $this->db->where('product_id', $rm);
                $this->db->update('products', $process);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Production Failed. 1 or more Raw Materials required for production is insufficient.');
            exit;
        }
}
$this->db->trans_commit();
```

there are insert and update statements afterwards but what i want is to stop the whole process if an exception is caught apparently the `exit;` statement doesn't do so

Comment: Are you using an INNODB database or a MYISAM database

Comment: You are mostly interested in testing if $nc >0 and stopping the process if it is not?

Comment: Is the code shown above in a model or controller?

Comment: @DFriend yes I also need to stop the process if an exception is caught
and the code shown above is a model

Comment: Nothing in that code actually *throws* an exception (and CodeIgniter doesn't do that either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a several ways to do this. Perhaps the easiest is this.

**Model:**

```
//I'm making the function up cause you don't show it
public function do_something(){ 

//all code the same up to here...

if($nc > 0){
    //Updates Count
    $process = array('count' => $nc);

    $this->db->where('table_id', $r);
    $this->db->update('table1', $process);
 } else {
     $this->db->trans_rollback();
     throw new Exception('Model whats_its_name has nothing to process');
 }
```

The catch statement in the model will catch any exception that the database class(es) might throw. (Do they throw any exceptions? I don't know.)

**Controller**

```
try{
    $this->some_model->do_something();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
 //catch the exception thrown in do_something()
 //additional handling here
}
```

All that said, it might be wise to check `$_POST['count']` for the appropriate values before you call `$this->some_model->do_something();`